# scheduler year view

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, fullcalendar, scheduler

im using angular in my website and i need a year view that will show all the events from each month without the specific date:

[image]

i didn't find any scheduler plugin that has this kind of view so im trying to do it by myself.
but my problem is when i want to add long events, that spreed over 2 month or more, i need to find a way to display and auto organize the events view order.
for example if i want to had 2 month event from july, this event will show first and push down all the short events:

[image]

but if i'll add another two month event from august, it will push down all the events on august, but on september it will leave one short event in the first cell and will not leave it empty:

[image]

the logic is exactly like fullcalendar or any other plugin, but i need this specific month view 
how can i implement this view if my server send jsons in this form:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try [Bootstrap Calendar](http://www.bootstrap-year-calendar.com/#Examples/Full%20example), it's simple to use.
You can find docs [here](https://github.com/Paul-DS/bootstrap-year-calendar)

Comment: but i cant manipulate this view to feat mine so how does it help me?

Comment: @ok Boostrap Calender perfectly do what you want to do. It can display a view of the year with tasks over multi months.

Comment: i don't want to see the days...just months